# lightGallery (jQuery plugin) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, lightgallery

I'm trying to get the lightGallery jQuery plugin (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/index.html) to work with AngularJS.

I found some answers that suggested I needed a directive, so I created the following:

```
.directive('lightGallery', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            jQuery(element).lightGallery();
        }
    };
})
```

Then in my view I do this:

```
<ul lightGallery>
    <li ng-repeat="photo in album.photos" data-src="{{photo.fullres}}">
        <img ng-src="{{photo.thumbnail}}" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

(I also tried with `<ul light-gallery>`)
When I run the page nothing happens when I click any of the thumbnails.
I can put an `alert()` in the link function, though, and that is displayed.

How can I get AngularJS to play along with jQuery and this plugin?

UPDATE:

After some debugging it seems that `jQuery(element).lightGallery()` is executed before the model is bound to the view.
So the question then is how I can get a directive to be called when everything is bound and not before.

Comment: How do you load lightGallery into AngularJS project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call lightGallery once ng-repeat is finished rendering.
You can just modify the directive like this

```
.directive('lightgallery', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.$last) {

        // ng-repeat is completed
        element.parent().lightGallery();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

HTML

```html
<ul>
  <li lightgallery ng-repeat="photo in photos" data-src="{{photo.fullres}}">
    <img ng-src="{{photo.thumbnail}}" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the demo [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nntLVOV58NmXbmB6LcIB?p=preview)

Comment: A follow up question. lightGallery documentation states that you can use the data-sub-html attribute to display captions for images. I added this attribute to the LI element, but nothing was displayed. I also tried adding a separate div (inside the LI) and referring to that instead, but that didn't work either. Any tips on how to use the captions when using AngularJS?

Comment: Caption works fine for me. I think your caption div doesn't have any style so it is hiding behind the image. Either you can use lightGallery default '.custom-html' class or you can apply css by yourself. here is the updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XqzhI1ZEmpcpQqdRIfjd?p=preview)

Comment: Ah, I was missing the .custom-html class. If I encapsulated my caption in a div with that class the captions works. The documentation might need updating as that says `<li data-sub-html="<h3>My caption</h3><p>My description..</p>" /> </li>` which is exactly what I had.

Comment: uh, isn't that instantiating multiple `lightgallery` widgets for each item?

Answer (score 0):

without directive..

HTML

```
<ul id="lightgallery">
  <li ng-repeat="image in album.images" data-src="{{imagem.fullres}}">
    <img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
// $http, Restangular whatever to return data in album.images

// unbind before..
jQuery('#lightgallery').unbind().removeData();

// $timeout after
$timeout(function () {
  jQuery('#lightgallery').lightGallery();
}, 100);
```

Works for me..

Comment: Maybe number 100 was sufficient for you. For sure this is highly unreliable

Comment: No. It has worked perfectly for 2 years on a large-scale project that uses this feature. : )

Comment: somehow only this solution solved my problem, maybe there could be other ways to do it. Perhaps instead of doing `removeData` there shall be a way to destroy instances of lightgallery. Better approach would be wrapping it inside angularjs directive.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of 2 directives allows you to specify a parent via a directive, as well as pass in options to a scoped variable, which provides the opportunity for more customization of Light Gallery.  The secondary directive triggers the parent to bind (using the same idea presented in @Clr's solution)

This directive is for the parent element, and you may pass a galleryOptions scope variable which is simply passed along when binding Light Gallery:

```
.directive('lightGallery', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            galleryOptions: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope) {

            this.initGallery = function() {
                $scope.elem.lightGallery($scope.galleryOptions);
            };

        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.elem = element;
        }
    }
})
```

This directive is for each "item" in the Light Gallery:

```
.directive('lightGalleryItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^lightGallery',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            if (scope.$last) {
                ctrl.initGallery();
            }

        }
    }
})
```

The resulting markup (which can really be anything you'd like by specifying the `selector` option when initializing Light Gallery):

```
<ul light-gallery gallery-options="galleryOptions">
    <li ng-repeat="photo in album.photos" data-src="{{photo.fullres}}" light-gallery-item>
        <img ng-src="{{photo.thumbnail}}" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Whereas options may be any valid Light Gallery options, such as:

```
$scope.galleryOptions = {
    selector: '.file-trigger',
    ...
};
```