# Load more button in AngularJS and lightGallery

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, lightgallery

I am using lightGallery for a website and I wanted to add a "load more" button to the gallery page, mostly for faster loading on mobile phones. I found various methods and tried them. Most of them don't work and/or doesn't suit my need for loading the elements on request.

One of them was with AngularJS:

```
var DemoApp = angular.module("DemoApp", []);
DemoApp.controller("DemoController",

function DemoController($scope) {
    $scope.quantity = 0;
    $scope.temp = [];
    $scope.loadMore = function () {
        for (i = $scope.quantity; i <= $scope.quantity + 1; i++) {
            $scope.temp.push($scope.images[i]);
        }
        $scope.quantity = i;
    }

    $scope.images = [{
        "src": "https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13244856_238092939903469_3778800896503555327_n.jpg?oh=e539748b060ba0cb43852314e2fdef0b&oe=57F01511"
    }, {
        "src": "https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13263891_238096316569798_4073904852035872297_n.jpg?oh=91a76b3515ac628706b912fdd3e9a346&oe=585C3DD1"
    }, {
        "src": "https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13260007_238096336569796_6324932140560503740_n.jpg?oh=1795ba25c4604dced3cdcc91b9729cc7&oe=5820EE5A"
    }, {
        "src": "https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12871473_238096353236461_8115646425269026926_n.jpg?oh=b8958326d24a1a649e6a40adf29b062b&oe=582BFD38"
    }, {
        "src": "https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13256520_238096376569792_9057528716929719317_n.jpg?oh=a6bc66f75992c88260ae35bd4dbc9ff1&oe=5856F934"
    }, {
        "src": "https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13254297_238096389903124_1429633590050411734_n.jpg?oh=5e8c94a0b6a77dea110704a5727e0ee5&oe=5819B551"
    }, {
        "src": "https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13267713_238096416569788_8740461856631991826_n.jpg?oh=739e3268996e498f65867b314265250b&oe=585E4C93"
    }];

    $scope.loadMore();
});
```

And this is my HTML mark up:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
<div id="fotoalbum" class="col-thumb-wrap">

<div class="col-thumb" ng-repeat="image in temp" data-src="{{image.src}}">
<a href="{{image.src}}">
<i class="thumb" style="background-image: url({{image.src}});"></i>
</a>
</div>

</div>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="loadMore()">Ik wil meer</button>
</div>
</div>
```

The "load more" button it self worked, however it broke the lightGallery itself.
Example: http://cytex.nl/projects/jk-installaties/album2.php

Then I found the solution for making lightGallery work with AngularJS in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220165/lightgallery-jquery-plugin-in-angularjs)

I tried to combine the two but it still doesn't work. Now lightGallery gets fired up OK, but the "load more" button doesn't do anything!

Example: http://cytex.nl/projects/jk-installaties/album1.php

```js
var DemoApp = angular.module('DemoApp', []);
DemoApp.controller('DemoController',
function DemoController($scope, $sce) {  
    $scope.total = 0;
  $scope.temp = [];
  $scope.loadMore = function () {
    for (x = $scope.total; x <= $scope.total + 1; x++) {
      $scope.temp.push($scope.photos[x]);
    }
    $scope.total = x;
  }

    $scope.photos = [{
        fullres: 'https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13244856_238092939903469_3778800896503555327_n.jpg?oh=e539748b060ba0cb43852314e2fdef0b&oe=57F01511'
    }, {
        fullres: 'https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13263891_238096316569798_4073904852035872297_n.jpg?oh=91a76b3515ac628706b912fdd3e9a346&oe=585C3DD1'
    }, {
        fullres: 'https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13260007_238096336569796_6324932140560503740_n.jpg?oh=1795ba25c4604dced3cdcc91b9729cc7&oe=5820EE5A'
    }, {
        fullres: 'https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12871473_238096353236461_8115646425269026926_n.jpg?oh=b8958326d24a1a649e6a40adf29b062b&oe=582BFD38'
    }, {
        fullres: 'https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13256520_238096376569792_9057528716929719317_n.jpg?oh=a6bc66f75992c88260ae35bd4dbc9ff1&oe=5856F934'
    }, {
        fullres: 'https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13254297_238096389903124_1429633590050411734_n.jpg?oh=5e8c94a0b6a77dea110704a5727e0ee5&oe=5819B551'
    },{
        fullres: 'https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13267713_238096416569788_8740461856631991826_n.jpg?oh=739e3268996e498f65867b314265250b&oe=585E4C93'
    }];

  $scope.loadMore();

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.photos.length; i++) {
        $scope.photos[i].fullres = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.photos[i].fullres);
    }
})
.directive('lightgallery', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.$last) {
        element.parent().lightGallery({
            showThumbByDefault: false
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

I am very new to AngularJS,so I'm sorry if this is a really stupid question. Could you guys help to identify the problem and maybe pointers on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append this fragment of your code to the last row of `loadMore` function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.photos.length; i++) {
        $scope.photos[i].fullres =      $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.photos[i].fullres);
    }
```

This part should be run each time you add an item to the array, It means this should be run each time the function `loadMore` triggers.
Hope this will be helpfull. Regards.

Comment: Thank you sir. Now that I look at my code with a "fresh pair of eyes", it makes so much sense. I can't believe I didn't see it sooner myself.

Comment: thank you for everything. Could you help me out with a follow up Q? I now have `(x = $scope.total; x <= $scope.total + 19; x++)` in an gallery with 102 items. It just loads until 100. I know it because of the "+19". What should I look into to let the code add the "remaining items if there isn't 19" ??

Comment: You're so welcome, Yea absolutely everything I can help. You can contact me with this email: ramin.king2004@gmail.com
For the last question you can set a condition if your items is less than your pagination size show them if not show only page size count (that equals 19 now).

Answer (score 0):

For others who ran into this issue:

The answer of Ramin Esfahani is of course correct. But you also have to destroy the lightGallery data ever time the "Load More" button is clicked. This is in done in the directive part. Of course change the "#fotoalbum" to your own ID or class. This is the code:

```js
.directive('lightgallery', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.$last) {
        element.parent().lightGallery({
            showThumbByDefault: false
        });
        $('#LoadMore').on('click', function(){
          $('#fotoalbum').data('lightGallery').destroy('true');
          $('#fotoalbum').lightGallery({
            showThumbByDefault: false
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };
})
```