# Angular directive in Typescript after ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm having an issue trying to make an Angular Directive in Typescript after a `ng-repeat` finish.

This is how I'm trying to make the directive work:

```
export interface ILightSliderInitDirectiveScope extends ng.IScope {
}
export class LightSliderInitDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public static DirectiveName: string = "lightSliderInit";
    link = (scope: ILightSliderInitDirectiveScope, $element: any, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => {
        if (scope.$watch('$scope.$last'))
            scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
    }
}
```

At the controller I have this method:

```
_self.$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function() {...});
```

And at the HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="it in items" light-slider-init>...</li>
```

The problem is that the directive works, but it go inside the if condition in every iteration of the `ng-repeat`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure you should be concerned with any "iteration" that may happen with an ng-repeat. All elements of it should be rendered during a single digest cycle, so for any normal use you should consider it as a single atomic operation. Why do you want this event? What do you plan to use it for?

Comment: I want execute a method with all the elements in the list to use the lightslider plugin.
http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30257914/1299394

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scope.$watch` returns a deregistration function for this listener, so `scope.$watch('whatever')` is always truthy. And you should not add `$scope` to the watched expression since it is evaluated regarding to the `$scope` object.
Here is what your code should looks like:

```
scope.$watch('$last', $last => {
  if ($last) scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend firing and event to do this because it makes it very difficult if you ever need 2 or more light sliders on the page.

Because this is in an `ng-repeat`, your link function will actually run for every instance in the repeater. So rather than `$watch`ing the value of `$last`, you should just execute your code on the last item in the repeater.

Code based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/30257914/1299394:

```
export class LightSliderInitDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope: ILightSliderInitDirectiveScope, element: JQuery, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            // This is the last item in the repeater
            // Instead of firing an event, just initialize the light gallery right here.
            element.parent().lightGallery();
        }
    }
};
```